# SOTI MobiControl does see my Managed configuration if I upload my apk manually

Tags: android, mdm, soti, android-restrictions, mobicontrol

I have a question regarding the correct method for exposing Android "Restrictions" in LOB (Line of Business) apps, particularly when uploading the APK.

My intention is to utilize my app as a LOB app by uploading the APK to SOTI MobiControl, and then configuring managed settings.

The current scenario is as follows: when I employ Managed Google Play, I can readily access my managed configuration `restrictions`. However, when I use the same version of the app and upload it as an APK, the managed configuration is not visible.

To illustrate, within SOTI MobiControl, the SOTI fails to display managed configurations of my app (unlike when it is utilized through Managed Google Play).
[image]

Here is my restrictions. Did I miss something?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<restrictions xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <restriction
        android:key="TestConfJson"
        android:title="@string/TestConfJson"
        android:restrictionType="string"
        android:defaultValue=""/>
</restrictions>
```

For example, it perfectly works for GlobalProtect_6.1.4.apk app, but not for my app.

Answer (score 0):

My app has min sdk version 19 and apk has the following structure
[image]

And after I had switched to min sdk version 21, it changed the structure.
[image]
And SOTI can read it now.

It sounds to me like SOTI has a bug on how to read this configuration.

I'm not expect SOTI will fix it because the `restriction` is part of API 21.